# Como dar mas tiempo de ejecución a una aplicación visual basic 6 de la misma forma como se hace en asp.net en la webconfig

Tags: asp.net, webservice, vb6

Tengo una aplicación asp.net, que llama a otra aplicacion web que es un webservice. Y para que funcione y no se caiga por el tiempo de espera a la aplicación del web service, inserto la siguiente linea de codigo en la webconfig de la aplicacion cliente de donde estoy llamando:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ServicioWebLecturaInsercionXMLCorreoSoap" closeTimeout="00:05:00"
                openTimeout="00:05:00" receiveTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="999999999"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="999999999" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:52155/ServicioWeb.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="ServicioWebLecturaInsercionXMLCorreoSoap"
            contract="ServicioWebClienteLeeXMLCorreo.ServicioWebLecturaInsercionXMLCorreoSoap"
            name="ServicioWebLecturaInsercionXMLCorreoSoap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Siendo asi, la forma correcta que me funciona. Pero estaba implementando otra aplicacion en visual basic, de escritorio, para llamar al webservice, y al ejecutarlo, se me cae. Me gustaría saber como le doy mas tiempo de espera, así como lo hice en la webconfig.

Comment: Como estas llamando al webservice desde la app de vb6? podes poner el codigo?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que se trata de vb6 y no vb.net?

Comment: Desde el  webservice voy obtiendo xml que genera, lo que esta dentro de los tags. Asi como asp.net, en la webconfig le daba mas tiempo para la ejecución del cliente(tal como lo puse antes), queria saber como le doy mas tiempo en vb6. No se si me explique bien?

Comment: @Danilo `Pero estaba implementando otra aplicacion en visual basic, de escritorio` ¿podemos ver el código de esta aplicación?, Si tu hiciste ese webservice, deberías revisar cuál es la causa de que el webservice necesite mas tiempo para responder.